# Can't post value using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

this is a part of my script to change the values of my select:

```
document.getElementById('poids').innerHTML = '<select onchange="peso();" class="form-control" required name="cat_poid"><option value="">Selectioner le poids</option><option value="-24">-24</option><option value="-29">-29</option><option value="-35">-35</option><option value="-41">-41</option><option value="+41">+41</option></select>';
```

Html :

```
<b>Poids: <div id="poids"><select class="form-control" name="cat_poid" required><option value="1">Selectioner le poids</option></select></div></b>
```

My problem is that I am creating a Form and I have a select that the values will change. 
So to change the values I used innerHTML and it worked perfectly. But the values won't post to the next page one the form is submited.

Once the script is called, the content of my DIV changes and I have the values needed. It looks impossible to POST the value that come from the innerHTML.

can anyone help ?

Comment: update your question with indenting by 4 spaces the code parts.

Comment: where you have submiting process

Comment: it's the first time I am posting something here, sorry, I didn't know about the 4 spaces ... Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could create a "dirty solution" ... it's pretty Ugly and I am sure there is a better way to do it.
Since I was posting to the next page but impossible te get the value I did something like this:

Just added it into my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="peso">
```

javascript:

```
function peso(){
var elem = document.getElementById("peso");
var pesos = document.getElementById("cat_poid").value;
elem.value = pesos;
};
```

My innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('poids').innerHTML = '<select onchange="peso();" class="form-control" 
required name="cat_poid"><option value="">Selectioner le poids</option><option 
value="-24">-24</option><option value="-29">-29</option></select>';
```

and the next page

```
$poid = $_POST['peso'];
```

but if I try to get the value like $_POST['cat_poid'];  i Have nothing ... I even used TemperData from FireFox to get exactly and edit the POST value and there is no cat_poid.

strange but the "dirty solution" worked.

Thanks everyone !!!! Solved ^^

Answer (score 0):

To update the selected item of a `select`, you have to set its `selectedIndex` which is 0 based. Also to add/remove items, you have to create DOM `option` elements and add them, or totally update the `select` element:

```
<div id="container">
  <select id="select" name="weight">
    <option>select the weight</option>
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

To manipulate that in JS:

```
// update with innerHTML:
document.getElementByID('container').innerHTML = '<select...>...</select>';
// or add an item with DOM model:
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = '35-40';
option.value = '35-40';
document.getElementByID('select').add(option);

// to select a specific option:
document.getElementByID('select').selectedIndex = 1; // selects the 2nd option
```

Comment: I tried exactly how you did but still not working. 
The problem is not to add the options but to POST the value of the options.



The InnerHTML works fine and the options are there with their value.


document.getElementById('poids').innerHTML = '<select class="form-control" required id="select" name="cat_poid"><option value="">Selectioner le poids</option><option value="-24">-24</option><option value="-29">-29</option></select>';



when I post my FORM , only the values from that SELECT wont be posted.

The way you posted I am having problem to make it work, not even add value I am able to.

Comment: When you say post, is it a HTML post, like clicking on the `submit` and having the browser going to the `action` URL, or is it a JS post somehow?

Comment: Exactly , I have <form action="inscriptions.php" method="POST">
<div id="poids"></div>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: Anything inside my form and not changed by innerHTML is posting correctly.... The only item not posting value to the next page is the select changed by innerHTML ...

Comment: hmmm weird, it should work. Not posting to next page? can you look at the Chrome inspector and inspect the POST request body in the network tab to ensure it is not sent?

Comment: I have the same problem. At browser request are Form Data correct but when I debug my PHP code on first line of first php file, then this input in $_POST is empty. And I have next problem. In browser FormData my input name is like array and is posted as array but in IDE debug i see the input as non array. All at localhost development.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the div's innerHTML completely. Just try to add or remove the options only.